# Ubuntu 20.04.4 freezes with no error

Tags: 20.04, freeze

I am at my wit's end. Lets start with my computer's hardware.

1. CPU: Ryzen 3500X
2. GPU: Nvidia GTX1660 Super
3. Motherboard: Asus b550m tuf plus gaming wifi
4. RAM: 2x 8GB Corsair Vengence
5. 1 SSD and 1 HDD for Windows

I am trying to install Ubuntu onto my desktop in a brand new SSD. However, after installation, it seems that Ubuntu would unexpectedly freeze. Everytime it freezes, I end up in a state where no emergency command works and I would need to force shutdown my desktop.

I have managed to update all ubuntu drivers and used Nvidia graphics drivers (before the freeze happens). I have also tried to remove my storage drivers for windows. But the results are still the same and the PC inevitably freezes, even when I am using the "try out Ubuntu" from my boot media. Somehow, my old laptop bought 6 years ago runs the same installation media perfectly fine.

I noticed that the freeze happens when I try to run something. Like opening Firefox to browse youtube or even sometimes during a system update. There is no error log generated each time this happens. So I have no idea what is happening internally. Would appreciate any help before I can get!

Edit: Things I have tried to do are

1. Installed and switched to Linux kernel 5.15.29
2. Change kernel boot parameters using "rcu_noobs=0-11 processor.max_cstate=5"
3. Change bios PSU Idle control to "typical current idle"
4. Update all packages and drivers, including GPU drivers
5. Installed Ubuntu 21.10 with and without 3rd party drivers
   Still, none of these have worked so far...

Comment: Hello. Is this a dual boot? Your question does not say that clearly. If it is freezing even with the try option for Ubuntu then its a good chance this machine as it stands will not run this version.

Comment: How big is the disk that you are installing Ubuntu on? Are you installing the AMD (64-bit)Ubuntu version?

Comment: @David I am installing Ubuntu in a separate drive, standalone. I did install Ubuntu with my windows storage drivers plugged out.

Comment: @Jeff the disk is a new Samsung EVO 870 500GB drive. I do not recall if what I have currently is the AMD version, I'll need to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I FOUND THE ANSWER!!! And I am using Ubuntu 20.04 with no problems for the last hour so far.

The solution was to update the BIOS. I removed all other changes too, so that I can confirm that the BIOS version was the only change needed to reach the solution.

Great thanks for everyone who pitched in to help me. It has been 1 week worth of nights of testing but I am glad I am finally here. =)

Comment: Benjamin What was the change to the BIOS that you did?

Comment: @Zanna why did you delete my question to Benjamin? His answer was about solving the problem with freezing of Ubuntu on AMD processors.

Comment: @John Rose, I updated the BIOS version to the latest version available. My update was found here: https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-GAMING-B550M-PLUS-WI-FI/HelpDesk_BIOS/

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I'll try that.

Answer (score 0):

Try a fresh install with version 21.10 downloaded freshly from [Official Ubuntu site](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). I think there might be some issues with 20.04 ISO you have or flashing tool. Use [Etcher tool](https://www.balena.io/etcher/) and don't see any reason else you might encounter this issue.

Comment: Check this Link for More Support (https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#1-overview) On official Ubuntu site there is proper step by step way which you can follow easily. Ubuntu officially also recommends Etcher over Rufus or other tools as it is easy.

Comment: @ExquisitE sure, I can try version 21.10 of Ubuntu. I am using Balena Etcher tool and I don't see any problems with that on my windows laptop.

Comment: Unfortunately, the freeze still exists...

Answer (score 0):

Web site https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/bugs.html#ID27 solves most freezing of boxes with amd processors.On mine, I was not able to do the PSU Idle Control mod as my BIOS does not have that parameter.

Comment: Done the change. The freeze still exists.